# Why doesn't android use default values for layout width and height? Can I achieve this on my own?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

I'm supremely frustrated by this actually.

I've just come from working on a project that uses Anko DSL layouts with a type-safe-builder that defaults `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content` unless you override them with some other value.

This alone drastically reduced the amount of code needed to get work done on layouts.

Now, I'm working for a company that uses XML layouts (for good reasons) and I'm once again feeling the pain of having to type `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` etc. over and over and over again for every single view.

Android has defaults for many of it's layout attributes, so I really don't understand why it doesn't have one for this.

Is there any way to achieve something like this?

I've tried using styles that set these values in them, but android studio still complains if I don't define the attributes for each view, even if it is defined in the style already.

I know there are similar questions to this already, but they are older and none of them had a conclusive answer one way or the other as to whether it is possible or not. I've done quite a bit of searching and turned up nothing, but this has to be a problem others have been frustrated by, and I find it hard to believe that nobody has come up with a solution.

Comment: Because there's a good chance that the default should be match_parent instead. Why not?

Comment: But that's my point. Pick one that seems more common and go with it. At least then *sometimes* I'll be saved from typing it. But I figured out the solution. You can't apply the styles via a theme - it has to be directly using the `style=...` attribute in the XML. If you do that, it won't complain.